# *ngFor output different HTML for every item in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, frontend, ngfor, ng-container, html-templates

I want to make notification bar and have HTML template as this one:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
    <div class="message"> ... </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But for different notifications, there should be different `message` templates, like these:

```
<div class="message"> <b>NEW</b> message arrived </div> or
<div class="message"> Message is <b>DELETED</b> </div> or
<div class="message"> Your message is <b>SENT</b> </div> etc...
```

I could make an *ugly method* in component to print message with these HTML tags, but is there more elegant way to this?

*ugly method:*

```
resolveMessage(status) {
  if (status == 'new') {
    return '<b>NEW</b> message arrived';
  } else if (status == 'sent') {
    return 'Your message is <b>SENT</b>';
  }
}

<div class="message"> {{ resolveMessage(notification.status) }} </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**components.ts**

```
messages = {
  new: `<b>NEW</b> message arrived`,
  sent: `Your message is <b>SENT</b>`,
  deleted: `Message is <b>DELETED</b>`
}
```

**template.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let notification of notifications">
  <div class="message" [innerHTML]="messages[notification.status]"></div>
</li>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/DPR3fgSh2sYieEMeG0Pu)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`*ngIf`** based on the status display the messages

```
<li *ngFor="let notification of notifications">      
    <div *ngIf="notification.status ==='new'" class="message"> NEW  message arrived</div>
</li>
```